# Is there any reason not to store api keys in cleartext?

Tags: api, security, api-key

I'm implementing an API for a CMS.

Clients are accessing the API via a public key or a private key (for more sensitive data). They can read AND write to the database with the private key.

I am storing the keys (just random strings) as cleartext in the database.

I've learned not to store passwords as cleartext. The main reason is, that a potential attacker could use the passwords on other systems (like facebook) where the user uses the same password.

This is not the case with apiKeys, as they are generated by the API itself and there only value is to grant access to the database. If an attacker made it that far, he already has access.

Having said that: Am I'm doing something wrong if I store api Keys as cleartext?

Comment: Why use the database and not a crypto store provider? (Or a crypto store provider to encrypt the data in the database.)

Comment: You may be misusing the terms 'public key' and 'private key'. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246071

Comment: OP is misusing public and private key. OP means "readonly key" and "read/write key". No asymmetric crypto involved in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong in stroring a key like this in clear text, but if you encrypt it it will add an extra layer of security. If someone breaks into your server and read the clear text keys from your database they can access your API using these keys. If encrpypted the keys will be of no use for an attacker.